# Min age check custom validation for MVC 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need some advice on custom validation for MVC 4.5 using my own custom data annotations

I am validating someones age when registering to a website.

I require these as fields to pass to the validator.

```
(date) date of birth
(date)event start date
(int)min age value
```

I store min age and event start date in the web.config. So this can be easily customized.
If a user's age is not old enough when checking the event date then they cannot register.

How do I go about doing this? I have checked some examples but I can't seem to get my head around it.

thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating your own validation attribute is the way to go and is easy to achieve.  To create one you just need to create a class that implements `ValidationAttribute`

**Example**

```
public class MinAgeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
       // Do some validation checks here
        var result = new ValidationResult("Sorry you are not old enough");

        return result;
    }
```

You override the `IsValid` method to do your validation logic, returning a  `ValidationResult`

Answer (score 0):

You can do custom validation by implementing IValidatableObject interface and then using Validate method. Check "[Using IValidatableObject Custom Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation_topic4.aspx)"

Please note that IValidatableObject only support server side validation. In my view it is better to have a server side validation in place. Just in case you are using the same method from a webservice call.

If you want custom client validation then try implementing IClientValidatable and ValidationAttribute

Comment: I wish people that recommended this would point out that it doesn't support client side validation.  It doesn't, which may be a huge issue.

Comment: @MystereMan : I agree it does not support client side validation. But then it is always better to have a server side validation in place. Just in case you are using the same method from a webservice call. If you want custom client validation then try implementing IClientValidatable

Comment: @ARS i would say that client side validation is just an extra thing you can add. OK it reduce traffic because you wont send to server empty forms, but server side validation is for real validation.

Comment: @ARS - You don't seem to understand.  You can't do client side validation with IValidatableObject.  You can't just implement IClientValidatable, you need to do the full attribute approach to get client validation, so your suggestion doesn't work.  Further, you seem to misunderstand that having client-side validation does not mean you don't have server-side validation.  Client-side happens in addition to server-side, so mentioning that is rather pointless, server-side is always there regardless of whether you have client or not.

Comment: @MystereMan: I think you didn't read my response properly. I guess you missed the point which state that IValidatableObject does server side validation only. Moreover the response also suggest to use ValidationAttribute and IClientValidatable to come up with a full blown attribute to do this validation. Finally I don't see it pointless in mentioning client side validation along with server side. It always helps when you state your point clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own annotation using **ValidationAttribute** and decorate it to required property. You have to overwrite **Validate()** method which returns boolean. and on the basis of that you can perform your operation

Answer (score 0):

It's not really necessary to create a custom attribute just for age validation.  All you need to do is create a custom property that calculates the age from the birthdate, then add a normal range validation attribute on the age property with a minimum age.

The problem, however, is that you are setting minimum age in the web.config, and attributes are created at compile time, not run-time.

I would suggest using Fluent Validation, as you can create far better validation scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

An example of the minimum age check attribute on .net core
Usage: [MinAge(18)]

Attribute:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MinAgeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int _limit;

    private readonly string _messageFormat;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="limit"></param>
    /// <param name="messageFormat"></param>
    public MinAgeAttribute(int limit, string messageFormat = null)
    {
        _limit = limit;
        _messageFormat = messageFormat;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if valid
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <param name="validationContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var bDay = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString());
        var today = DateTime.Today;
        var age = today.Year - bDay.Year;
        if (bDay > today.AddYears(-age))
        {
            age--;
        }

        if (age >= _limit) return null;
        var message = _messageFormat.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "Sorry you are not old enough" : string.Format(_messageFormat, _limit);

        var result = new ValidationResult(message);
        return result;
    }
}
```